How do I pass the MItem, that defines an Imperative Expression in the visibleWhen-Clause, to the Imperative Expressions @Evaluate method?
In Eclipse e4 RCP one can control the visibility of ToolBar and Menu items by adding a visible-when expression in the model definition.
I want to use e4 style imperative expressions instead of the old core expressions.
Imperative expressions are defined by creating a class with a method that is annotated with @Evaluate and which returns a boolean.
My question is as follows:
When the @Evaluate-method is eventually called, is it possible to somehow find out for which MItem the method is called?
I can pass the eclipse context into the method via dependency injection, get the MApplication object and from there look for any MItem. However, the problem is that I don't know which MItem to look for.
I doesn't work to inject the MItem into the method directly like one can inject an MPart into a handler for example.
What do I want to achieve:
My program can be run in several "modes" (think of it like different perspectives). Depending on the mode different menu and toolbar items are supposed to be visible or invisible.
However, I don't want to create a different imperative expression for every item to control its visibility.
And I don't want to create one giant imperative expression that defines each items visibility individually inside its method body.
It should be doable with one general imperative expression.
My thinking was to add tags (in the model editor) to each item for every mode in which the item is visible.
For example, let's call the modes A, B and C. I'd like to add the tags "A" and "B" to an item, if it is supposed to be visible in modes A and B, but invisible in mode C.
For that to work, I need to be able to find out for which MItem the @Evaluate method was called. Then I can get the tags from the item and compare it with the current mode.

It doesn't look like the current element is made available to the imperative expression (source is org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ContributionsAnalyzer.isImperativeExpressionVisible. Could you have one expression for each "mode" - I have one RCP that uses about 20 imperative expressions for different combinations of settings and elements.

One expression for each mode doesn't work unfortunately. I forgot to mention, that the user has the option to hide individual toolbar elements in the settings. So I have to check not only the mode, but also the user settings in the evaluate method. And for the latter I also need to know which item I'm dealing with.

It doesn't seem to be possible to get the current item in the imperative expression.
You can get the current imperative expression model object MImperativeExpression and that can also have tags set.
@Evaluate
public boolean test(MImperativeExpression expression)
{
  List<String> tags = expression.getTags();
  
  ...


Works with the current eclipse. Thank you for finding a solution. Unfortunately, it does  not work for me, because I'm on an older target platform (4.11). For the time being, I decided to patch org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ContributionsAnalyzer.isImperativeExpressionVisible. Before the invocation of the evaluate method I put the current item into a context variable and set a null value right after the invocation. Ugly hack, but seems to work fine.
